# Group homomorphisms form an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1, G_2) = \{f:G_1\to G_2 \mid f $ is a morphism $\}$. Show that $(\mathrm{Hom}(G_1, G_2), +)$ is an abelian group.

I had problems just with the closure property! How do you show that $f+g$ is a morphism? I should add that $(G_1,\cdot)$ and $(G_2,\cdot)$ are abelian groups?

Comment: Only $G_2$ abelian should be enough. (Otherwise, you can get two group homomorphisms $f,g:\mathbb Z\to S_3$ such that $f+g$ is not a group homomorphism.)

Answer (score 1):

Show that it has the required properties. In particular,
$$\begin{align}(f+g)(x+y)&=f(x+y)+g(x+y)\\&=f(x)+f(y)+g(x)+g(y)\\&=f(x)+g(x)+f(y)+g(y)\\&=(f+g)(x)+(f+g)(y)\end{align}$$

Comment: First of all, the OP denotes the operations on $G_i$ multiplicatively. Second, if $G_2$ is not commutative your try can fail.